# How to implement a singleton in NextJS?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm making a NextJS app and my configuration object that's used everywhere inside the app has complex logic to initialize it. Its contents as well as how it is initialized depend on a bunch of things that change depending on the deployment environment and I need to make sure it's only initialized once even though it is accessed from everywhere inside the app.

Usually I'd do this by saving the instance somewhere inside the global object after checking it doesn't exist or I'd make a class with a private constructor and a method to get the instance, but neither approach seems to work in NextJS. Here's an example of my implementation. I'm using the app router.

```
// Exporting the config object, this is imported everywhere in the app and referenced
export const config: Constants = {
    ...
    customerSettings: CustomerSettings.fromEnv(),
}
```

```
// defining the CustomerSettings class which should be a singleton
import { cleanEnv, str } from "envalid"
import { CustomerSpecifficLangaugeKey, SupportedLanguage } from "./sharedTypes"

export default class CustomerSettings {
    private static instance: CustomerSettings
    private constructor(
        private readonly customerText: Record<SupportedLanguage, Record<CustomerSpecifficLangaugeKey, string>>,
    ) {
        // I want this to only be invoked once, when the singleton is initialized
        console.log("===initialize CustomerSettings===")
    }

    public getCustomerText() {
        // some implementation here returning data
    }

    public static fromEnv(): CustomerSettings {
        if (!this.instance) {
            const argsFromEnv = cleanEnv(process.env, {
                ...
            })
            this.instance = new CustomerSettings(argsFromEnv)
        }

        return this.instance
    }
}
```

```
"use server"

import { config } from "@/lib/constants"

export async function testConst() {
    return config.customerSettings.getCustomerText()
}
```

```
// Home page where I'm testing the server action behaviour
const Home: NextPage = function () {
    return <main>
        <form action={testConst}>
            <button type="submit">TEST</button>
        </form>
    </main>
}
```

I'd expect to get one console log with "===initialize CustomerSettings===", but I get a log whenever i click the button. I played around and it seems like the global object is being re-created for every invocation of the server action and the class definitions are being re-done every time, meaning the CustomerSettings class from the first invocation isn't the CustomerSettings class that exists on the second invocation. If I modify my server action to do a little experiment like this:

```
"use server"

import { bemsConfig } from "@/lib/constants"

export async function testConst() {
    if (!(global as any).TEST_VAR) {
        console.log("=====> TEST_VAR not set")
        ;(global as any).TEST_VAR = 0
    }
    return bemsConfig.customerSettings.getCustomerText()
}
```

I get a console log on every invocation, confirming that the global object is different.

Is there any way around this? I need to be able to control how my code is executed as performance is a consideration and there are operations that will take a bunch of time. If every invocation of a server actions needs to re-create the universe it will seriously impact the performance of my server.

Comment: nextjs use multi process

Comment: mate use ai chat

Comment: Obviously I tried asking chat GPT and it gave me a long and detailed answer which was entirely wrong and hallucinated.